# How to get response from SCPG3 command

Tags: powershell, sftp

I'm using scpg3 command to copy file from local server to a remote server. My command is as below:

```
scpg3 <filename> user@remotehost:/tmp
```

My question is: how to get the result from this command. I want to move it to backup folder after copy successfully. Thanks

Comment: With WinSCP: [Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload)

Comment: Thanks Martin, but is there any way to do this with scpg3?

Comment: Probably, I do not know `scpg3`, that's why I've posted it as a comment only.

Comment: Thank you, I will try WinSCP instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a verbose directly. You can use that:

```
scpg3 -v, --verbose
```

in your case,

```
scpg3 -v <filename> user@remotehost:/tmp
```

Uses verbose mode which is equal to -D 2. `-D` only applies on Unix. On Windows, instead of this command line tool, use the Connection Broker debugging options -D, -l.

D is the Debug level.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try it and feedback to you. Thanksss